# Internet Explorer find out when a user navigates away from the page

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, navigation, detect

I am using VS2008 (C++) to create an IE plugin that creates a child window. It is like a normal Explorer window, but customized to fit my needs. I want to destroy the window when the user navigates away from the page, by calling DestroyWindow().

I do not know how to detect if the user has navigated away. Is there an event listener/handler that I can put in my code to accomplish this?.

I have seen a few in javascript that does that, but I need to use C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sync the Navigate() events in DWebBrowser2, and determine if the target URL is outside the context that you care about.

Comment: I actually handled the BeforeNavigate2 event (in DWebBrowserEvents2) that gets fired when a user navigates away. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: So basically, you did what I suggested.  :-)